# setAutoFocusEnabled(true) doesn't work although my device supports auto focus

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-camera, google-vision, android-vision

I'm trying to create a barcode reader. The program works perfectly when the barcode is big. To read small barcodes i will need autofocus enabled.

I added setAutoFocusEnabled(true) to cameraSource, but it doesnt work.

How can i fix the following code to get autofocus working?

My testting device is a samsung galaxy J1 sm111m android 5.1.1 API 22

```
package com.gutimore.android.pdf417;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.SparseArray;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.Barcode;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.barcode.BarcodeDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SurfaceView cameraPreview;
    TextView txtResult;
    BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector;
    CameraSource cameraSource;


    final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RequestCameraPermissionID: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return;
                    }
                    try {
                        cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraPreview = findViewById(R.id.cameraPreview);
        txtResult = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);

        barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(this)
                .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.PDF417)
                .build();
        cameraSource = new CameraSource
                .Builder(this, barcodeDetector)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(640, 480)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();


        //Add Event
        cameraPreview.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    //Request permission
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestCameraPermissionID);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(cameraPreview.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
                cameraSource.stop();

            }
        });

        barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                final SparseArray<Barcode> qrcodes = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if(qrcodes.size() != 0)
                {
                    txtResult.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            //Create vibrate
                            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vibrator.vibrate(1000);
                            txtResult.setText(qrcodes.valueAt(0).displayValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally, moved to ZXing and everything works like a charm!

https://github.com/zxing/zxing

Answer (score 0):

Use `CamaraSource` from ([link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/barcode-reader/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/barcodereader/ui/camera/CameraSource.java))

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.barcodereader.ui.camera;
```

And initialize, as below

```
CameraSource camera = new CameraSource.Builder(requireContext(), barcodeDetector)
   .setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
   .build();
```

But on some old samsung devices autofocus still won't be working. Better use ZXing